# I am trying to make a simple authentication request using HTTPClient but am receiving an error

Tags: java, http, rest, authentication, apache-httpclient-4.x

http://developer.dnb.com/docs/2.0/common/authentication-process

The authentication process of the service I  am trying to access is explained in the url above. It is a simple REST authentication process wherein the user-id and password are passed in as follows:

```
POST https://maxcvservices.dnb.com/rest/Authentication
x-dnb-user: MyUsername
x-dnb-pwd: MyPassword
```

I have tried the following code but am receiving `HTTP/1.1 400 ERROR`. I am unable to figure out what I am doing wrong as I am very new to Java and HttpClient in particular. Any help would be much appreciated.

I have thus far tried the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
        try {
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("https://maxcvservices.dnb.com/rest/Authentication");
            List <NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList <NameValuePair>();
            nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("x-dnb-user", "myusername"));
            nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("x-dnb-pwd", "mypassword"));
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps));
            CloseableHttpResponse response2 = httpclient.execute(httpPost);

            try {
                System.out.println(response2.getStatusLine());
                HttpEntity entity2 = response2.getEntity();
                // do something useful with the response body
                // and ensure it is fully consumed
                EntityUtils.consume(entity2);
            } finally {
                response2.close();
            }
        } finally {
            httpclient.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Often the response body contains a meaningful error message.

Answer (score 2):

you need to set the username and password to http header

```
            httPost.addHeader("x-dnb-user", "myusername");
            httPost.addHeader("x-dnb-pwd", "mypassword");
```

as it expects those in the http header

Answer (score 1):

You can use Jersey - RESTful Web Services in Java.

Download [Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/).

```
Client client = Client.create();
    String auth = new String(Base64.encode("UserName:Password"));
   String url = "https://maxcvservices.dnb.com/rest/Authentication";
    WebResource webResource = client
           .resource(url);
    ClientResponse response = webResource.header("Authorization", "Basic " + auth).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).accept("application/json").get(ClientResponse.class);

   if (response.getStatus() != 200) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                + response.getStatus());
    }

    String output = response.getEntity(String.class);
    System.out.println(output);
```

Change Username and Password.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
        try {
//          
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("https://maxcvservices.dnb.com/rest/Authentication");
            httpPost.setHeader("x-dnb-user","myusername");
            httpPost.setHeader("x-dnb-pwd","mypassword");
            //List <NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList <NameValuePair>();
            //nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("x-dnb-user", "myusername"));
            //nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("x-dnb-pwd", "mypassword"));
            //httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps));
            CloseableHttpResponse response2 = httpclient.execute(httpPost);

            try {
                System.out.println(response2.getStatusLine());
                HttpEntity entity2 = response2.getEntity();
                // do something useful with the response body
                // and ensure it is fully consumed
                EntityUtils.consume(entity2);
            } finally {
                response2.close();
            }
        } finally {
            httpclient.close();
        }
    }
```

Apparently the username and password was supposed to be passed in using a Header (although I don't know what the advantage or security implications of this design choice are) in the HttpPost request which is what the following two lines in the above code achieve:

```
 httpPost.setHeader("x-dnb-user","myusername");
 httpPost.setHeader("x-dnb-pwd","mypassword");
```

Comment: i don't think there's much of a security implication since the communication done over https

Answer (score 0):

The d&b documentation says that the username and password should be sent in request header s, but your code is sending them in the body.

Instead of adding them as name/ value pairs in an entity, set them as request headers, e.g.

`httpPost.setHeader("x-dnb-user", "my username");`